# Class (function) as stream sink

Tags: c++, stream, operators

I would like to provide a method for a static class to input values by stream.

Instead of:

```
MyClass::inputText("some text");
MyClass::inputText(std::to_string(123));
```

I would like to have:

```
MyClass << "some text";
MyClass << 123;
```

or better configurable:

```
MyClass(config) << "some text";
MyClass(config) << 123;
```

Searching the internet, I only found tutorials how to implement << and >> with the class as argument not as sink.

Can someone give me a hint, how to do that?

Comment: What's a static class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `MyClass` a static instance of some other class:

```
class MyClass_t {
    template <typename T>
    MyClass_t operator<<(T const& ) { ... }
};

static MyClass_t MyClass;
```

That way, you can just use it as you want:

```
MyClass << 123; // calls MyClass_t::operator<<(int const& )
```

Making `MyClass(config)` work can go in multiple ways. Either `MyClass` is a function that takes a config and returns an instance of some object that is streamable. Or it's a class and that expression will create a temporary that will be destroyed at the end of the line (maybe you can take advantage of that and have `~MyClass()` do something special).